# Remove elements that have attribute with a value that matches to some other element's attribute value

Tags: xslt

Suppose I have the following input file:

```
<root>
  <container_items>
    <item Id="a">
      <Content Name="red_dark" />
    </item>
    <item Id="b">
      <Content Name="yellow" />
    </item>
    <item Id="c">
      <Content Name="blue_dark" />
    </item>
    <item Id="d">
      <Content Name="green" />
    </item>
  </container_items>

  <container_refs>
    <item_ref Id="a" />
    <item_ref Id="b" />
    <item_ref Id="c" />
    <item_ref Id="d" />
  </container_refs>
</root>
```

The real file is a little more complicated, but I will make it look simpler with closer criteria here to remove those 'item' elements that have 'Content' child element with a Name attribute that ends with "_dark". I managed to remove the 'item' elements that I don't need, however, the corresponding 'item_ref' elements left. Let's say I removed the 'item' elements that match my criteria. My goal is the 'item_ref' elements with Id="a" or ="c" also to be removed (those are the Id's of the matched and removed 'item' elements). So the expected end result is.

```
<root>
  <container_items>
    <item Id="b">
      <Content Name="yellow" />
    </item>
    <item Id="d">
      <Content Name="green" />
    </item>
  </container_items>

  <container_refs>
    <item_ref Id="b" />
    <item_ref Id="d" />
  </container_refs>
</root>
```

Apparently, I need to remove all 'item_ref' elements that have Id attribute with a value in the list of values collected from certain 'item' elements' Id attributes (that match my existing criteria for 'item' elements).

My XSL file is the following (focusing only on the criteria):

```
<xsl:template match="//item[./Content[substring(@Name, string-length(@Name)- string-length('_dark') + 1) = '_dark']]" />
```

Based on my criteria the 'item' elements matching the criteria are removed, but then the associated 'item_ref' elements remain in the input file, causing the following result:

```
<root>
  <container_items>
    <item Id="b">
      <Content Name="yellow" />
    </item>
    <item Id="d">
      <Content Name="green" />
    </item>
  </container_items>

  <container_refs>
    <item_ref Id="a" />
    <item_ref Id="b" />
    <item_ref Id="c" />
    <item_ref Id="d" />
  </container_refs>
</root>
```

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with a `xsl:key` and two empty templates:

```
<xsl:key name="items" match="container_items/item" use="@Id" />
```

and the two empty templates are

```
<xsl:template match="container_items/item[substring(Content/@Name, string-length(Content/@Name)-string-length('_dark') + 1) = '_dark']" /> 
<xsl:template match="container_refs/item_ref[substring(key('items',@Id)/Content/@Name,string-length(key('items',@Id)/Content/@Name)-string-length('_dark') + 1) = '_dark']" />
```

The first one removes the `item`s from `container_items` and the second one removes the `item_ref`s from the `container_refs`.

Comment: I don't think the key() is required in the first template, at this point you are already in the item context.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have complications to apply it to my real scenario. I will share my original criteria (little complicated). The container_refs block stays the same, but, in the container_items block the 'item' elements have a bit different structure. In a real example I have it like this <item Id="b"><Content  Name="yellow"></item>. And then my criteria to remove unnecessary 'item' elements is: <xsl:template match="//item[./Content[substring(@Name, string-length(@Name)- string-length('_dark') + 1) = '_dark']]" />. So having this criteria, how would you define the key and templates?

Comment: I changed my solution. I hope that this version will suit your needs.

Comment: @zx485, sorry but your update for the new structure didn't work.

Comment: I checked the code with the following XML: `<container_items>
    <item Id="a">
      <Content Name="red_dark" />
    </item>
    <item Id="b">
      <Content Name="yellow" />
    </item>
    <item Id="c">
      <Content Name="blue_dark" />
    </item>
    <item Id="d">
      <Content Name="green" />
    </item>
  </container_items>` and with `Content/@Name`, the output is as desired.

Comment: I updated my question description to be closer to my real scenario. Please, update your answer if my update is clear.

Comment: Great. I re-checked your new code with the last version of my above answer. And my answer is working well.

Comment: I confirm, it worked for me as well. My bad, I missed a simple prefix for my real life element. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Define a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key)** as:

```
<xsl:key name="item" match="item" use="@Id" />
```

then use:

```
<xsl:template match="item_ref[substring(key('item', @Id)/@Name, string-length(key('item', @Id)/@Name) - string-length('_dark') + 1) = '_dark']"/>
```

to remove the `item_ref` nodes.

There's probably a more efficient way to do this by storing the relevant Ids in a variable, but that's the general idea.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have complications to apply it to my real scenario. I will share my original criteria (little complicated). The container_refs block stays the same, but, in the container_items block the 'item' elements have a bit different structure. In a real example I have it like this <item Id="b"><Content  Name="yellow"></item>. And then my criteria to remove unnecessary 'item' elements is: <xsl:template match="//item[./Content[substring(@Name, string-length(@Name)- string-length('_dark') + 1) = '_dark']]" />. So having this criteria, how would you define the key and templates?

Comment: I am afraid this is a bit difficult to follow. Either edit your question to reflect your real scenario or post a new one.

Comment: I updated my question description to be closer to my real scenario. Please, update your answer if my update is clear.

Comment: With zx485's answer which was similar to Michael's it worked for me. Thank you @michael.hor257k.

Comment: It seems like a trivial adjustment - you should be able to do it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a way to do it.
You could optimize the //item[...] by using a key call.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="item[contains(@Name,'_dark')]"/>

  <xsl:template match="item_ref">
      <xsl:variable name="ir" select="."/>
      <xsl:if test="//item[@Id=$ir/@Id and not(contains(@Name,'_dark'))]">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:attribute name="Id"><xsl:value-of select="@Id"/></xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFepP

Comment: I updated my question description to be closer to my real scenario. Please, update your answer if my update is clear.